# Is it possible to block the random Effect of Gaussian Noise in several channels of a RGB image

Tags: image-processing

[image]

Consider a RGB image, `Lena` sample image. We've added an `GaussianNoise`.

Actually, I think, the `GaussianNoise` process was evaluated three times.

So my question is Can we block the GaussianNoise like that of `BlockRandom`,

For example, if we run something `BlockRandomGaussian`, then

If we do

```
imgN1=ImageEffect[img1,{"GaussianNoise"}]
imgN2=ImageEffect[img2,{"GaussianNoise"}]
```

Here the Gaussian Noise of imgN1 and imgN2 are the same.

Comment: Please see the `RandomSeeding` option which can be used on the `ImageEffect` function.

Comment: @kirma  OK, Thanks, I didn't try it before, it works fine on `GaussianNoise`